# How to handle SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED in Python to download data properly

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, airflow

To sum up what I'm working on:

I need to run a DAG on Airflow that'll download some files from a public dataset, an american agency.

Even after some days reading and testing plenty of solutions through previous posts here, I'm still facing this error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)>
```

My code snippet responsible for that is the following:

```
import urllib.request
from contextlib import closing
from shutil import copyfileobj
from time import sleep
from airflow import AirflowException
import certifi
import ssl 


# Set the SSL certificate authority bundle to use certifi
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
        
# download file
tries = 0
while tries < 5:
    try:
        with closing(urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ssl_context)) as r:
            with open(cdc_file, "wb") as f:
                copyfileobj(r, f)
            print("File has been downloaded and copied successfully")
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"####### Error: {str(e)} #######")
        print("####### Sleeping for 10 secs before trying again #######")
        sleep(10)
        print("####### Trying again #######")
        tries += 1
        if tries >= 5:
            raise AirflowException("It wasn't possible to download NOAA files due to connection refused by NOAA's server")
        continue
```

Before coming here for your help, that's I've tried so far:

1. created an unverified ssl context on dev env for testing purposes - I wouldn't be able to run this on prod. Anyway, it didn't work (403 forbidden)
2. created this while loop with 10s sleep before trying again to avoid multiple and fast requests
3. updated certifi and ssl packages, and it didn't work as well (same cert_verify_failed result)
4. creating a custom pem file with the CA certificate that I got from 'openssl s_client -connect downloads.psl.noaa.gov:443 -showcerts' (note: the server that I'm trying to download data from is that one indeed)

To give you a little more context: using ec2 running Amazon Linux 2, Airflow 2.1 and Python 3.7

That's it! Thanks in advance!

Tried items 1 to 4 as mentioned before

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: Sure @AndrejKesely! 

This one is a sample link, just as those ones I've been trying:

https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.dailyavgs/surface_gauss/cfnlf.sfc.gauss.2023.nc

Comment: When I do `open("cfnlf.sfc.gauss.2023.nc", "wb").write(requests.get("https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.dailyavgs/surface_gauss/cfnlf.sfc.gauss.2023.nc").content)` I successfully download the file. From where are you running the code? Maybe the IP addresses are blocked.

Comment: ec2 instance? they're located in us-east-1,

I'll try out this approach right now! fingers crossed! Thanks a ton, @AndrejKesely

Comment: And when you try to run the code from your computer, it works?

Comment: Yep, it works flawlessly

Comment: Then the IP addresses of EC2 instances are blocked on the server.

Comment: I guess so! Same result using those functions you coded! Thanks anyway! Much appreciated